# Rename wp-login.php with default permalink

Tags: authentication, wordpress, wordpress-login

For better security, I would like to rename the login url of my blog to something other than /wp-login.php. I found a plugin that would do the Job

http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/

But the problem is that it works only with non-default permalinks, which is a problem for me, because I use unicode names for my topics, which could make the link very long and messy with percent encoding. I wouldn't want to translate every link name to english... that's tedious!

Is there a way to hide wp-login.php and wp-admin from hackers without having to change the permalink form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use [Rename wp-login.php](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) plugin with any kind of permalink structure! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest one great plugin that have plenty useful things in it and also what you want. And it uses other technique, that is not dependent on permalinks (in two words - it uses htaccess for all the magic).

It's called `Better WP Security`.
Here is the [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a permalink structure like this?
/%post_id%/

Comment: Actually it's a good idea and I would do that, except that I will lose my records of "ShareThis" plugin... it's annoying to reset everything!

Answer (score 0):

From long time i was tackiling with one issue.
some one trying to access my website using random password.
i got report of ip addresss, who hits wp-login.php files.

beside that i found .sd0 file in my root folder.
that file filled with some encrypted code.

I removed this and change my wp-login.php to wp-login-xx.php
After changed this file you required to change below file also to get proper execution.

1. search for wp-login.php and replace this with your assign name (wp-login-xx.php)

   wp-login.php
   wp-includes/general-template.php
   wp-includes/pluggable.php
2. for better security also update wordpress with latest one.